# Select specific file from a folder

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Hi I am trying to select an image from a folder based on the how blurred it is. I am able to determine the most blurred image but now I want to select this image and use it as a background for further computation. Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this.

```
def variance_of_laplacian(file_list):

    for bb, file in enumerate (glob.glob(path)):
        image = cv2.imread(file)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur_extent = cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_64F).var()
#         max_blur = min(blur_extent)
        print(blur_extent)
variance_of_laplacian((glob.glob(path)))
```

This code gives me the blurriness in an image and I want to select the most blurred image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, simply check if the blur_extent of the current image is higher than the blurr of the blurriest and update. Then finally return the blurriest.

```
def variance_of_laplacian(file_list):
    blurriest = 0 
    blurr = 0
    for bb, file in enumerate (glob.glob(path)):
        image = cv2.imread(file)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur_extent = cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_64F).var()

        if blurr == 0:
            blurr = blur_extent
        if blur_extent < blurr:
            blurriest = image

        print(blur_extent)
    return blurriest

blurriest = variance_of_laplacian((glob.glob(path)))
```

Comment: I am getting an error that ```cannot unpack non-iterable int object```

Comment: It is still showing the wrong one. In my data set I have the image 1 as the blurriest but it shows image 0. For a different data set even, it is only displaying image 0 as the answer

Comment: Is the variable blurr_extent larger if the image is blurrier or smaller?

Comment: The variable is smaller for more blur image

Comment: Then you just have to flip the 'blur_extent > blurr' to 'blurr < blur_extent'